# Chasing a monster on a $3 \times 3$ grid

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> There are nine rooms as shown below $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline1&2&3\\\hline4&5&6\\\hline7&8&9\\\hline\end{array}.$$ A monster is in one of the rooms. Each turn, the people open $k$ different rooms and check if the monster is inside. If the monster isn’t seen, it will go to another room that has a common side with the previous one.
>
> Find $k$ for which people can guarantee finding the monster.

I proved $k=3$ works.

First, while the monster is hidden, its room number will go in a cycle of odd and even.

Open rooms $(2,4,6);(2,4,6);(5,7,9);(5,7,9)$ in the first four turns in this order. I’ll prove this works by separating the problem into two cases:

- The room number of the monster is odd-even-odd-even in the first four turns. Then in the second turn the monster must be in room $8$ or else it is found. So in the third turn the monster must be found.
- The room number of the monster is even-odd-even-odd in the first four turns. Then in the third turn the monster must be in room $8$ or else it is found. So in the fourth turn the monster must be found.

But how to prove $k<3$ doesn’t work?

Comment: $k=1$ is easy.  Each room has at least two exits, so always move to a room which is not about to be opened

Comment: Does the monster move while the doors are open or after they have been closed?

Comment: How does this strategy find the monster if it goes 8-5-2-1?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Strategy problem" says nothing about the subject of the problem.

Comment: @eyeballfrog After closing the doors. This is really weird because it’s like finding a strategy for the monster and that seems impossible since the monster doesn’t know the strategy of the people.

Comment: In that case, after opening 2 4 6 twice, the monster could be in any of them. Starting at 8, moving to 5, then moving to (for example) 6.

Comment: I think we have to assume the monster does know the strategy of the people. One person can randomly guess, and the probability the monster can stay hidden for $n$ turns goes to zero, but we don't want that to count as a strategy. It's customary anyway in these logical game theory questions to look for a strategy which is effective even if the opponents know your exact strategy.

Comment: For $k=3$ the people can win in four turns, by searching for a monster that starts even then for a monster that starts odd (or of course vice versa).

Comment: Of course, it takes $k=4$ people to win in two turns, or $k=9$ people to win in one. :)

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? It would help other people to refer to it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose the monster is even-numbered. Open rooms 2 and 4. If the monster isn't caught, it is now odd-numbered and not in room 1. Now open rooms 3 and 5. If the monster isn't caught, it is now even-numbered and not in room 2. Open rooms 4 and 6. If the monster isn't caught, it is in room 8, and becomes an odd numbered monster in room 5, 7, or 9. Open rooms 5 and 7. If the monster isn't caught, it is in room 9, and becomes an even-numbered monster in room 6 or 8. Open those doors. If the monster isn't caught, it is an odd-numbered monster, and becomes an even-numbered monster. Repeat to catch him.

Answer (score 3):

(@eyeballfrog posted an essentially identical answer shortly before I did. I'll leave this up just as a different way of describing it.)

When $k=2$, the people can win within 10 turns:

$$(2,4); (3,5); (6,8); (5,7); (2,4); (2,4); (3,5); (6,8); (5,7); (2,4)$$

Let $M_n$ be the number of the monster's room on turn $n$, $1 \leq n \leq 10$.

If $M_1$ is even and the monster stays hidden, then $M_1 = 6$ or $M_1 = 8$. If not found on turn 2, $M_2 = 7$ or $M_2 = 9$, but it can't be in room 1. If $M_2 = 9$ then the monster is found on turn 3. If $M_2 = 7$ the monster can only hide with $M_3 = 4$, then $M_4 = 1$, but then must be found on turn 5.

If $M_1$ is odd, the first five guesses will all miss the monster, but then the monster can't stay hidden for guesses 6 through 10 for the same reasons as above.

Comment: $k=1$ seems quite unreasonable but can we prove it?

Comment: Sure. Every room has at least two adjacent rooms. The monster just needs to move every turn to a room which will not be the one guess on the next turn.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to catch the monster when $k=2$.

Start by checking two rooms adjacent to a corner, say, rooms $2$ and $4$. If you do not catch the monster, on the next turn, you know it is not in room $1$. This is progress.

On the next turn, check rooms $3$ and $5$. Since $1$ was eliminated by the previous turn, this means that all of room $2$'s neighbors are cleared, so on the next turn, we have eliminated room $2$ (but room $1$ is now possible again).

On the third turn, check rooms $4$ and $6$. Since $2$ was eliminated by the previous turn, this implies that all of the neighbors of both rooms $1$ and $3$ have been cleared, so on the next turn, we have eliminated rooms $1$ and $3$.

Continuing in this fashion, you can reach a point where all rooms are eliminated, which means at some point previous you must have caught the monster. I leave the details of fleshing out the rest of this strategy to you, dear reader.

---

It is also easy to prove $k=1$ is impossible. The monster can evade capture forever while only using the rooms numbered $1,2,4$ and $5$. It survives by using this strategy: move in the cycle $1\to 2\to 4\to 5\to 1\to \dots$ over and over, unless the next room in the cycle is the room that the player will check next turn. In that case, the monster should instead backtrack.

This of course assumes that the monster can read the human's mind. However, even if the monster just randomly moves, there is a finite chance it will follow this strategy for any finite number of turns. Therefore, with $k=1$, there is a finite chance a random monster will evade capture for any period of time, meaning you cannot guarantee capture with $k=1$.

Comment: What if the monster's rooms for the first three turns are 1, 2, 1; or 1, 2, 3?

Comment: It appears that the first *two* moves are checking rooms 2 and 4, so in either case, you'd catch the monster on the second turn.